# Compilation error using snowflake COPY INTO internal stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

Trying to do a simple unload of a Snowflake table to internal staging.  Creating the stage works just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE stage dm15152_stage FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE='CSV' COMPRESSION='GZIP')
Stage area DM15152_STAGE successfully created.
```

But copying the table fails

```
COPY INTO dm15152_stage FROM DM15152
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 29 unexpected 'DM15152'.
```

The table exists, I can select rows e.g. `SELECT * FROM DM15152 LIMIT 10`.
I must be doing something wrong, but all of the examples I can find look like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer seems stupidly simple, but I thought I should post it because it defies the examples I could find.  It works by using a path syntax:

```
COPY INTO @dm15152_stage/data.gz FROM DM15152
```

Comment: I would still like to see other answers, as this seems a bit under-represented in available examples.

Comment: It has nothing to do with path but the @ simbol before stage name, when referencing the stage in load unload copy command, one must need to use the @ before stage name